# How to sync two or more Mercurial servers?

Tags: mercurial, synchronization, repository

I want to keep Mercurial servers at four different locations, and want them to be identical at any given time. Meaning, any change to any of them must be propagated to all other servers. How to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add an action on the server with an `incoming` hook.

Hooks allow you to automate tasks when events happen on the repository. Whenever you get a push into the repository, you can push to your mirrors as well.

More on hooks: http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html

Comment: You're better off using the 'changegroup' hook instead of the 'incoming' hook.  That will push all the csets at once instead of run the hook one for each cset.

Comment: What if somebody pushes to one of the mirrors at the same time somebody pushes to another.  If all of the mirrors just push to one another it seems like one would get race conditions where pushes would fail.  Thanks.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's why you only push to one repo. The idea of a mirror is to have a backup. You never wake up and say "Which face am I going to shave today? The one my hands are attached to or the one in the mirror?" At least, I hope you don't. :) Therefore, things should only ever be checked *in* to one of those servers. This is okay, because you probably do 1000x more reading than writing to your repo. (History, diffs, branch changes, etc.) So, if the "primary" server is far away and a checkin is slightly slower, nobody will ever notice! I hope this helps!